# Should I include publications where I am a "team member" in my CV

Tags: publications, cv, authorship

Related to but different from [Should I include a publication where I'm only acknowledged (and not one of the authors) in my CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/should-i-include-a-publication-where-im-only-acknowledged-and-not-one-of-the-a)

I'm a part of some publications which officially are written by author A and B and then the Team Members. Should these publications be on my CV? I contributed to the project (hence the team co-authorship) but don't want to seem like I'm trying to pad my CV.

Currently I have my publication list broken up by sections: Journal, Talks, Technical Reports, and then Other, and I have the Team Member publications listed under Other.

Is this appropriated and/or reasonable, or should I remove them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at the CV that's linked to your website, I don't see anything inappropriate about what you've done. The only thing to make sure of is that when you have a team listed explicitly as the author in a paper (e.g., "Author X, Author Y, and The A-Team"), you will need to make sure that there is a publicly available listing of the team members available for reference. This could be as a supplement to the paper online (as "supporting information"), or it can be on a permanent web site for the team's endeavors. However, people should be able to confirm that you are a member of this collaboration beyond just what's on your CV.

Answer (score 8):

- If you are listed as an author in the paper, then you can always include the paper in your publications list.
- If you are pruning your resume to be a 2-page one and if you have better publications (say where you are the lead author) to show, then have a single category titled "Selected Publications" and exclude this paper.
- If you are making a very detailed list of publications, say one on a webpage, then do consider including the name of all authors in the same order as in the published paper.