# Do you include papers that you contributed to but weren't cited as an author in on your CV?

Tags: graduate-school, cv

I'm an undergraduate and about to apply to graduate school. I did summer research that contributed to a paper and was asked to extend my time there to write the publication but could not stay due to academic reasons. Because I contributed to it, is it appropriate to include it on my CV?

Comment: Why isn't your name on this paper?

Comment: They said that the if I wanted my name on it, I'd have to stay back to help write it.

Comment: Significant data collection, preparation, and analysis crosses my threshold for authorship easily. The Internet is also a great mechanism for exchanging drafts and collaborating on writing. I find cutting a student out for not being physically present and not finding ways to work them into authorship pretty sad.

Comment: @BillBarth - I would recommend not turning this question into a discussion on whether the OP *should* have been included as an author, because that really won't lead to anywhere useful. It's entirely possible you're right, but at this point, it's water under the keel.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/should-i-include-a-publication-where-im-only-acknowledged-and-not-one-of-the-a

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar situation, there were a few papers I assisted with as an undergraduate where I was listed in the acknowledgements but wasn't listed as an author. Generally, people don't list those on their CV, simply because it will look odd... you'll get a lot of people asking, "why are you listing this if your name isn't on it?"

That said, since it's your CV, you can list anything you want with the proper commentary. You may consider listing it as:

> <Citation goes here>
>
> *Note: I am listed in the acknowledgements section for this paper, as I assisted extensively with data preparation and analysis.*

Do realize that the fact that your name isn't on the paper will *significantly* decrease it's value in your promoting yourself. The more I think about it, it's probably a bad idea to list it... I would recommend just listing the work you did in the appropriate section on your CV and leave the paper out.

Comment: When describing the work, you could add a note like "This work contributed to the following publication: ...".