is being mentioned in acknowledgements section of a paper worth putting on a CV?
Recently, there was a paper that asked for both antibacterial and anti-adhesion assays against bacteria.  I contributed and performed all these tests but in the end, the other authors decided to omit me from the authors' list and put me in the acknowledgments section. They were not going to change their mind and I had only two options whether to have my name removed completely or remain in the acknowledgments.
I was wondering if it is a good idea to put this paper in my resume or not.

This question was already asked here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/should-i-include-a-publication-where-im-only-acknowledged-and-not-one-of-the-a?rq=1

I would not put a paper in the CV on which I am not a co-author. However, I would consider describing my contribution to that paper in something like a cover letter and briefly mention the acknowledgement as a confirmation that your statement is true. Being on the acknowledgments does not always imply an important achievement, so I would not mention it unless you have the possibility to summarize your contribution in writing.
Edit: Depending on your (academic) age, the fact that you've chosen to mention such a minor thing as being mentioned somewhere in the acknowledgments might be seen negatively by some, implying that you have no other achievements to mention. For an undergraduate or 1st-year PhD, this could be an achievement, but otherwise I would consider skipping it altogether or mentioning it only in passing, without much emphasis. If you already have a PhD or are nearing the end of your PhD, you will be expected to have your own publications against which you can be assessed.

thank u for the answer. i must say that im on my masters and ive got only 1 paper with my name on it, so that's why I asked this question.
